# Create a column of one hot encodings, add empty columns for missing categories

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to populate values from one df to another df.

Df1 looks as such with shape (52,2):

```
Providing 1st 5 rows of df1:

     id            months 
71911200001          22
71911200002          27
71911200004          30
71911200003          23
41911200003          35
```

Df2 looks as such with shape (52,49):

```
Providing 1st 5 rows and columns of df2:

id           M0 M1 M2 M3 M4.....M49
71911200001  0  0  0  0  0       0
71911200002  0  0  0  0  0       0
71911200004  0  0  0  0  0       0
71911200003  0  0  0  0  0       0
41911200003  0  0  0  0  0       0
Note: id is set as row index for this df.
```

Now I want to populate Df2 in such a manner that it looks like below:

```
id           M0 M1....M22 M23...M27...M30...M35..M49
71911200001  0  0      1   0    0     0      0    0
71911200002  0  0      0   0    1     0      0    0
71911200004  0  0      0   0    0     1      0    0
71911200003  0  0      0   1    0     0      0    0
41911200003  0  0      0   0    0     0      1    0

The ids are the same on both the dfs.
```

Basically, for each id's in df2 I want to populate "1", wherever the numeric part of the column name in df2 matches the value in the months column of df1.

Note: All the ids are unique and there are no duplicates.

Any help on the above will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need df2? I feel like you could just construct `df2` from `df1` using [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) on a [categorical column](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html). Try this:

```
df['months'] = pd.Categorical(
    df['months'], categories=range(50), ordered=True)

df2 = (pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('id')['months'], dtype=np.int8)
         .add_prefix('M'))
```

```
df2.shape
# (5, 50)

df2.loc[:, 'M22':'M27']

             M22  M23  M24  M25  M26  M27
id                                       
71911200001    1    0    0    0    0    0
71911200002    0    0    0    0    0    1
71911200004    0    0    0    0    0    0
71911200003    0    1    0    0    0    0
41911200003    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

`df2` is now a DataFrame of one hot encodings. Every category from M0-M49 is represented.

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need is to modify your `df2`'s columns that are from `df1` `months` column as:

```
df2[df1["months"].map("M{}".format)] = pd.get_dummies(
    df1["months"], prefix="M", prefix_sep=""
)
```

Assign those columns the values from `get_dummies` obtained from `df1[months]`

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
out = (pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('id')['months'])
.reindex(columns=range(50), fill_value=0)
.add_prefix('M'))
```

**Check**

check `out.loc[:, 'M22':'M27']`

```
            M22 M23 M24 M25 M26 M27
id                      
71911200001 1   0   0   0   0   0
71911200002 0   0   0   0   0   1
71911200004 0   0   0   0   0   0
71911200003 0   1   0   0   0   0
41911200003 0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by iterating over the rows of df1 and updating the corresponding rows of df2 based on the id and months values, try this out:

```
for idx, row in df1.iterrows():
    id_value = row['id']
    month_value = row['months']
    df2.loc[id_value, f'M{month_value}'] = 1
```